# Magento 2 credit memo API observer/plugin

Tags: api, rest-api, magento2.2.2, soap, creditmemo

I'm interested to know if an observer or plugin will be trigger if a credit memo is created via API rest example: `POST /V1/creditmemo/refund` OR `POST /V1/invoice/{invoiceId}/refund` 
ref:https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesRefundInvoiceV1

ref:https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesCreditmemoManagementV1/salesCreditmemoManagementV1RefundPost

I basically need to check/detect for external parties creating refunds in my Magento application.

That said I need to catch data `before` or `after` observer/plugin method for a refund and probably just log it somewhere in a file in Magento.

Any one done it b4 ? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes events will be triggered in your scenario. The only thing to keep in mind is that API execution happens in its own area. So if you want to add an event observer just for those use `etc/webapi/events.xml` (`etc/frontend/events.xml` would not get executed).

Comment: Appreciate I will give a try. I am assuming all api's will trigger event observer/plugin ? E.G: offline returns using `V1/order/:orderId/refund`